# Excel error: expected end of statement, what does this mean?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write this formula into a cell via my script:

```
  strFormulas(1) = "=IF(AND(I2<12.2,I2>=8.2),"t","f")"
```

And it keeps coming up as an error, even though it works just fine in the actual sheet if I manually input it into the cell. What is it expecting me to do here?

Comment: Is the leading = being handled properly? Your quotes? What's inserted via the script may not be what you actually expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape quotes. Try this:

```
strFormulas(1) = "=IF(AND(I2<12.2,I2>=8.2),""t"",""f"")"
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue that you are running into is that `"` is interpreted as beginning or ending a VBA string.  So VBA parses your expression as

```
strFormulas(1) = "=IF(AND(I2<12.2,I2>=8.2),"
```

with "garbage" at the end.  This "garbage" is what it is complaining about.  If you need to include a `"` within a VBA string, use `""`.